# Issues removing specific children in react js

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, children, removechild

When I try to remove a child changing the state it sets an older state... So instead of deleting 1 item it removes everything after it.

I tried splice, filter, slice and other methods to manipulate the array I'm using for state.

The code here :

https://codesandbox.io/embed/tender-meitner-s75d4?fontsize=14

And this is what is not working because something I don't get about the state.

```
const removeChildRule = index => {
let newArrayRule = [...rules];
newArrayRule.splice(index, 1);
setRules(newArrayRule);
};
```

The element chosen to be deleted should be deleted alone. Not with all children before it.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just filter the array instead of splice it :

```
const removeChildRule = index => {
  let newArrayRule =rules.filter( r => r!= index );
  setRules(newArrayRule);
};
```

Comment: I think the issue is not in the splice, the issue is in the whole code. just need more to debug the whole code. because if you remove splice code still things are not working FOR ME

Comment: OK im checking your sandbox, thnks!

Comment: I think that the key prop in your ````Rule```` component could be breaking your code. Look at this [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) and try to assign a value that you are sure that is unique.